# HAC Standard Error and Non HAC Standard Error

Tags: r, confidence-interval, standard-error

A rolling window regression estimate as per follows:
data= datam, 60 windows per period

```
datam=cbind(unempts,gdpts)
datam <-matrix(datam,ncol=2)
out <- rollapplyr(datam,
                  width = 60,
                  FUN = function(x) coef(lm(as.data.frame(x))),
                  by.column=FALSE)
plot((out[,2]),type="l")
```

In this plot also need to add the confidence interval by using the HAC and non-HAC SE for the slope coefficent. To get the SE I tried

```
coeftest(out[,2],vcov. = out[,2]$hacse)
```

But I get an error -

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Please advise on what I am going wrong.

Comment: You need more details. What kind of data are you putting in. This typically happens when you are subsetting wrong.

Comment: @AbdalahEl-Barrad the data in out is coeffients from lm, [,1] for intercept and [,2] for slope

Comment: head(outm)
     (Intercept)         V2
[1,]    7.046241 -0.3939213
[2,]    6.962879 -0.3867624
[3,]    6.750484 -0.3423529
[4,]    6.557447 -0.2992243
[5,]    6.432825 -0.2718148
[6,]    6.383905 -0.2631228

Comment: Try coeftest(out, vcov. = hacse)

Comment: @AbdalahEl-Barrad its the same error. This code was suggested by someone. Can you identify what is the regression object being created as. I am confused between out and x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your example reproducible I took unemployment and GDP data from Greene's econometrics textbook as available in the `AER` package. I also took GDP returns rather than GDP in levels:

```
data("USMacroG", package = "AER")
datam <- ts.intersect(
  unemp = USMacroG[, "unemp"],
  gdp = diff(log(USMacroG[, "unemp"]))
)
```

The rolling regression can then be carried out via the `zoo` package:

```
library("zoo")
out <- rollapplyr(datam, width = 60, by.column = FALSE,
  FUN = function(x) coef(lm(as.data.frame(x))))
```

The resulting object `out` is then a time series object (class `"ts"`) in which only the two regression coefficients (intercept and slope) are stored.

```
class(out)
## [1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"
head(out, 3)
##      (Intercept)      gdp
## [1,]    4.896035 2.104652
## [2,]    4.878405 2.307698
## [3,]    4.870110 2.397435
```

Therefore, plotting the second column yields the changing GDP return slope over time:

```
plot(out[, 2])
```

[image: slope time series]

So to obtain standard errors in addition to the coefficients these need to be stored in the `out` time series. Various flavors of HAC standard errors (Andrews kernel HAC, Newey-West, etc.) can be obtained with the `sandwich` package. For a single linear regression:

```
reg <- lm(as.data.frame(datam))
coef(reg)
## (Intercept)         gdp 
##    5.677756    2.945576 
sqrt(diag(vcov(reg)))
## (Intercept)         gdp 
##   0.1101139   1.5414225 
library("sandwich")
sqrt(diag(kernHAC(reg)))
## (Intercept)         gdp 
##    1.543329    2.810953
```

As you can see, the HAC standard errors are substantially larger due to the positive autocorrelation in the data (which is likely better modeled explicitly rather than captured through HAC standard errors).

```
out <- rollapplyr(datam, width = 60, by.column = FALSE,
  FUN = function(x) {
    reg <- lm(as.data.frame(x))
    c(
      "slope" = coef(reg)[2],
      "se" = sqrt(diag(vcov(reg)))[2],
      "hacse" = sqrt(diag(kernHAC(reg)))[2]
    )
  })
```

This yields the estimated slope and the two kinds of standard errors:

```
head(out, 3)
##      slope.gdp   se.gdp hacse.gdp
## [1,]  2.104652 1.482968  2.079983
## [2,]  2.307698 1.491482  2.153506
## [3,]  2.397435 1.532250  2.278149
```

And from this you could create further plots etc. The model in the example does not really fit particularly well and is rather questionable. But I hope it is clear(er) now how the R code works.

Comment: Easy to understand and comprehensive solution, all of the above worked

Answer (score 0):

We are really no ready to address the topic that you are posing in the title of your questions because there are more basic errors and lots of ambiguities that need to be clarified. The error is from `out[,2]$hacse`. The `out[,2]` part returns a vector and you cannot use `$` to access components of a vector.

In your comments you ask where the regression object is. It what is returned by `lm(as.data.frame(x))` to the function `coef`, which the the coef function then discards, but there are further problems with that. There is no formula. So I don't understand what you are trying to do. Your description of the `datam` object is to sketchy to allow much further comment. Why don't you produce `str(datam)` and also explain what you are really hoping to do. (There is no function `rollapplyr` in the default packages so you need to include a `library` call as well.)